# Testing searchkick with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I would like to create feature specs for searching Patients in my Practice Management app.

So far, I have searched the net and have followed suggested solutions from:

http://bitsandbit.es/post/11295134047/unit-testing-with-tire-and-elastic-search#disqus_thread

and

https://github.com/karmi/tire/wiki/Integration-Testing-Rails-Models-with-Tire

Both of these articles suggested configurations to spec_helper.rb for ElasticSearch and Tire. Since Searchkick was based on Tire, I applied the solutions to the class Patient, which is the only model I am using Searchkick on.

However, I get a 'NoMEthodError' for each of the configurations.
For example, using the following code:

spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config| do
  .
  .
  .

  config.before :each do
    Patient.index.delete
    Patient.create_elasticsearch_index
  end

  config.before :all do
   Patient.index_name('test' + Patient.model_name.plural)
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `index_name'
```

The same happens to the methods 'index' and 'create_elasticsearch_index'

I am fairly new to RoR and am honestly not sure what I could be doing wrong here, except maybe for assuming I could use Tire solutions on Searchkick. So any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 34):

Searchkick needs better testing documentation, but here's the gist of it:

Searchkick automatically uses a different index name in each environment, so no need to do any set up. Run `Patient.searchkick_index.name` in the console to confirm this.

Instead of deleting and recreating the index, you can just call `reindex`.

```
RSpec.configure do |config| do
  config.before :each do
    Patient.reindex
  end
end
```

Finally, after inserting data, call `Patient.searchkick_index.refresh` before calling `Patient.search`. This tells Elasticsearch to update the index immediately (rather than after the refresh interval, which defaults to 1 second).

Comment: Awesome!!! You're an absolute lifesaver :D And massive thanks for the gem as it has saved me tons of time from setting up ElasticSearch.

Comment: @andrew-kane, I seem to only be able to get my rspec working correctly if after inserting my data in my spec using let!, I simply call the Model.reindex in the before block.  If I call Model.searchkick_index.refresh, then data is not inserted.  I can verify though in the application that the index is readily searchable after I insert the data.  I am not doing anything special (ie. no async or bulk).

Answer (score -3):

Even if Searchkick was based on Tire, that doesn't mean that the Tire methods are available on your models. See https://github.com/ankane/searchkick for documentation on what methods *are* available. See the subsection https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#migrating-from-tire in particular for a contrast between using Searchkick and using Tire.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I researched on the links you provided. I saw that the index_name method is still used within Searchkick but in the form of 'searchkick index_name: 'new_index_name'', instead of directly calling the method on the class. I apologise if the answer seems to elude me on this one. However, my problem is in the context of a test environment and not on the class Models which are the ones provided in the searchkick documentations.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. What does the test environment context have to do with how you use the API?

Comment: Yes, the last sentence did sound confusing. I was essentially looking for test docs on how to set it up on RSpec. The creator of searchkick  posted the solution below. But thanks for the help, still! :D